# How to prevent fragmentation of MySQL data files?

Tags: mysql, defragmentation

I think this question was asked many times, but searching for it I have found only some notes in some responses.
I know that files are generally handled by OS+filesystem, but there are (or should be) methods to change this. Other big DB systems use at least file preallocation and growing by adding up big chunks. As I know, MySQL lacks this type of features (or is my knowledge outdated?) and it can offer only `OPTIMIZE TABLE` which *defragments* the records inside the files, but the files themselves could be very fragmented.

As a specific problem, I have a table that should act as a *stack*: a lot of `INSERT`s and `DELETE`s, the data has a short life (from several seconds to hours), the maximum size of the *stack* is known. The table will be modified often - thousands of times per day, and there are others *active* tables too, so this scenario will cause a very fragmented layout of the disk over time. My current idea is to preallocate the entire *stack* table and then use a *top index* and just `UPDATE`s.

Anyway, besides my specific problem (it would be nice to have a solution for it too), **What are the used methods to diminish or even eliminate defragmantation (if possible) of MySQL data files, both MyISAM and InnoDB, preferably on *nix systems?**  and is *raw devices* a solution at least for InnoDB?

Comment: For your specific problem, did you consider a NoSQL database? Redis looks like a good choice for what you need.

Comment: @Sam: does Redis lack this particular type of problems like fragmentation generated by the DB software itself?

Comment: Redis is an in-memory database, so file fragmentation is not an issue. There might indeed be memory fragmentation, you would have to check out if that is an issue for your specific problem. Sorry, I can't give you a more concrete answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the stack to survive server/mysql reboot, and it fits in memory, create the table as a MEMORY table.

--HHS